# unable to fill data into application with cucumber

Tags: cucumber-junit

I already have a selenium code for Salesforce and am using JUnit and Cucumber to pass data. Now am adding another application to this code,But am unable to pass the values into application with cucumber.Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide some more information? (I cannot comment until I have 50 rep) Like stack trace or error you receive? Are you trying to open the other application in the same browser? Or a new browser? Is it in the same feature file?